# How to prevent build for new branch creation in azure devops yaml

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

In Azure DevOps, created pipeline using Yaml file and mentioned "develop" under Triggers section. It is triggering for new commits in develop branch but also triggering for new branch creation based on "develop" branch which is not happening when I create a static pipeline. How can I prevent build for new branch. Any help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the include / exclude filters like below :

```yaml
# this is being defined in app-ci pipeline
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: securitylib
    source: security-lib-ci
    trigger: 
      branches:
        include: 
        - releases/*
        exclude:
        - releases/old*
```

Just check this page and you should find your answer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops

Regards

Comment: Hello Alexandre,
I tried that but still pipeline is triggering for new branch creation. See my code below

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - refs/heads/develop
  batch: True
name: $(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
    type: git
    ref: refs/heads/develop

Comment: I think you should only include th branch you want to trigger and exclude all others like  :  include: 
        - refs/heads/develop
        exclude:
        - refs/heads/*

Comment: After using include: refs/heads/develop alone it is working fine. Thank you

Comment: Can you add +1 and mark as resolved please ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this ?

```
 trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from 2020 or 2021 [this is possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#behavior-of-triggers-when-new-branches-are-created). Just put a Path filter in your yaml:

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
      - /
```

For example in my pipeline yaml definition I use this:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - feature/*
  paths:
    include:
      - /
```

If you use old classic pipelines, the answer is always Path filters. [You can see here how](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/prevent-create-a-new-branch-from-triggering-a-buil/394272).